# ArcGIS 10 tool (add x,y) is not working

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I have a problem with go to X, Y tool in arcgis 10. When I want to use this tool the program crashes. Is there any service pack or something to repair that problem?

Comment: There is a service pack but I am not so sure that there is not another problem.  

First, which tool are you using, the arcscript from zahid, or the pointlocator in arcmap?   
Have you tried using the tool in a new mxd document with only one layer?  
Are you using a standard ESRI coordinate system?  

If you are using the arcscript from zahid I suggest contacting him as it probably doesn't have much to do with arcmap.

Comment: I am using the pointlocator in arcmap.
I have tried using the tool in a new mxd with no layers, one layer and also with two and more layers.
I am using the WGS 84 coordinate system.
I can admit that in ArcGis 9.3 this tool was working perfectly.

Comment: Mine works in 10. however I have noticed that sometimes it won't put the point on when I just select the point. I have to select the point with callout. Do you have support for 10? If so you might submit a support request. Do you recieve a message after crash? The software should generate a dmp log of the crash and offer to send that to arcgiserrorreport@esri.com . If it doesn't send it will ask a location to save it local. You can then send an email to esri. Not sure what could be causing this. The only other thing I can suggest is to try different coordinate systems and settings in pointloc.

Comment: My thoughts are along the same lines as Brad's.

I've had no trouble using either Go To XY (on the Tools toolbar) or Display XY Data (on context menu of a table) in ArcMap 10 and 10 SP1.  

I've assumed that by "pointlocator in arcmap" you mean the Add Labeled Point button on the Go To XY tool dialog so I tested that, as well as Add Point and Add Callout.  

My testing was done with the Coordinate System of my data frame set to GCS_GDA_1994 Datum: D_GDA_1994.

Comment: Hi, I am having same problem. ArcMap crashes when I click on the go to XY button and the message "serious application error" comes up. I am working with korean coordinate system. 

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema,al presionar el boton ir XY se cierra arcmap. será que tiene que ver con los pc de 64bits... 
porque en los computadores de 32 no tiene ningun problema !!!

Comment: @Jose, please see [Handling questions from non-english writers](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228/handling-questions-from-non-english-writers). We simply don't have a large enough user base to use multiple languages. Feel free to use your native tongue in the [GIS chat site](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133/gis).

Comment: @ Jose, por favor, ver [preguntas Manejo de los no-escritores Inglés](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228/handling-questions-from-non-english-writers). Nosotros simplemente no tienen una gran base de usuarios suficiente como para utilizar varios idiomas. Siéntase libre de utilizar su lengua nativa en el [SIG sitio de chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133/gis).

Comment: everyone, please use *comments* when asking for more information and/or conducting a back-and-forth exchange and reserve *answers* for answers. The design and purpose of the site's system is to make the final solutions float to the top and not get buried in traditional forum-style threads. Thanks. (also see http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: I have the same problem with te "Go to XY tool" in ArcGIS 10, and I haven't found a solution yet.. Any suggestions? THANKS a lot!

Comment: I, personally, don't have this problem but one of our clients has this issue on all their ArcGIS 10 SP3 workstations (Windows XP). They haven't been able to track down the issue yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcGIS 10 - service pack 1 - http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=66&MetaID=1685

Comment: Unfortunately, installing service pack1 did not help. I have still the same problem. I was digging through the internet but still i did not find any solution. It is really weird for me that only this function (tool) is not working...

Comment: I find that's happening to me also.

Comment: SP4 is now available - http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=66&MetaID=1843 if you still have the issue submit a ticket with ESRI support.